# Xamarin MarcTron AdMob banner is not working

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, admob, ads

In my xamarin app, i want to show a banner with MarcTron. I think I made all the steps correctly (appId, banner id, etc...) but in the page, it makes space for the banner but the banner is blank. Any Ideas? Does this lib still work?

The app id and banner id are the ones that admob gave me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I had to replace MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext); with CrossMTAdmob.Current.Init(this, "my_app_key"); in the MainActivity
2. To show the banner i had to call banenr.LoadAd();. It does not load it automatically any more.